# How to remove fieldPermissions from Profile via metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, permissions, profile, delete

We manage to create new fieldPermissions by calling `updateMetadata()` and passing to it a Profile object with the new fieldPermissions.

However, we haven't figured out a way to remove specific fieldPermissions nor a Profile object.

For example, if we want to change an object's custom field's permissions from standard to admin, we can only add the admin but can't remove the standard permissions.
We've tried removing the Profile object but got an error from the metadata API: "cannot delete profile".

Example:

The current state of a field we wish to change:
admin: { editable: true, readable: true },

The desired state:
standard: { editable: true, readable: true },

What we end up with:
admin: { editable: true, readable: true },
standard: { editable: true, readable: true },

(because we can add the standard fieldPermission to the field but can't remove the admin fieldPermission)

How do we achieve that?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and provide more details around "if we want to change an object's custom field's permissions from standard to admin", can you give an example of a permission, and the desired end state?

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan done.

Comment: Object permissions aren't categorized as "standard" or "admin". Those are different Profiles, which are modified separately. How is your code selecting a Profile to modify?

Comment: Consider using [Muted Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_set_groups_muting.htm&type=5) if / when they go GA

Comment: @DavidReed indeed the profile we modify is picked by the field level security. For example to add admin permissions to MyCustomObject type, the profile which we will add the field permission will be "Admin". The field permissions are named by the field's full name. For example: 
"{
        field: MyCustomObject__c.Address__c",
        editable: permissions.editable,
        readable: permissions.readable,
}".
Adding such field permission to a Profile is easy, the unknown is how to remove one.

Comment: @BrianMiller we need to perform the operations via the API, didn't see this feature in the Metadata API

Comment: @ybro as David is saying, permissions are not categorized that way, unless it's an area of the API that we are not familiar with. Do you have a link to the official API documentation where you are getting this from? Typically to remove permissions from a profile via the Metadata API, you need to deploy the XML of that profile, without including the xml tags for the fields in question.

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan this is the link to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm). We use the [updateMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_updateMetadata.htm) API call to send it the Profile info without the [field permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/#profilefieldlevelsecurity_title) we no longer require.
But when we fetch the Profile, it shows that the new permissions were added but the ones that were omitted are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the solution was to update the fieldPermissions to editable: false & readable: false on the relevant Profile object.
That is the proper way to remove a field permission for a custom object through the Metadata API.
The downside for it, is that the field permission will remain the the Profile object and will "garbage" the Profile.